# Empty Review Queue Redlight

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

I thought the redlight for review queues meant they were backed up.

[image]

Is this a new bug? I've cleared my cache and I still see it's got a red-light.

Comment: There is more caching involved other than your browser's cache.

Comment: Some people are fast. Really fast. Absurdly fast. So fast they can clear the entire queue in the time it takes you to move your mouse down and click on the Triage button to open up the queue.

Comment: @yivi thanks so do you know the solution for the problem?

Comment: @AndréKool. Hahaha, I like that answer

Comment: @johnny5 Wait a bit, so the involved caches are invalidated. Problem fixed. Invalidating caches is one of the 2 easy problems in programming, so it shouldn't take long.

Comment: @yivi that and naming variables

Comment: And off-by-one errors.

Comment: Not exactly a cache, more of a... Lots of reviewers all active at once, with soft locks on the posts they're reviewing.